# How to prove that the algebra $k[x, xy, xy^2, xy^3, \dotsc]$ is not finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Consider the subalgebra $R=k[x,xy,xy^2,xy^3, \ldots] \subset k[x,y]$. How do I prove that $R$ is not finitely generated (over $k$)?

What is the general strategy for proving that an algebra is not finitely generated?

Comment: $k$ is any field.

Comment: Can a non-noetherian ring finitely generated over a field ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $R$ is generated by $f_1,\dots,f_n$ over $k$, which are polynomials in terms of $xy^m$ up to $m = M$. ($M$ is finite since there are finitely many $f_1,\dots,f_n$). This would imply that $R = k + (x,xy,\dots,xy^M)$. Now we can go back to your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274590/how-to-prove-this-subring-is-non-noetherian) to see that for example, $xy^{M+1}$ does not lie in $(x,xy,\dots,xy^M)$.