# Generators of certain $R \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, finitely-generated

Let $h \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ with $\deg(h)=d \geq 1$
and let $R_{h,y}:=\mathbb{C}+\langle h,y \rangle \subseteq 
\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

It is known that subalgebras of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ are finitely generated, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45690/must-k-subalgebra-of-kx-be-finitely-generated?noredirect=1&lq=1),
therefore, $\mathbb{C}+\langle h \rangle$ is finitely generated, and it is generated by $\{h,xh,\ldots,x^{d-1}h\}$.
For example, for $h=x^2$ we obtain $\mathbb{C}+\langle x^2 \rangle=\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3]$,
so a finite set of generators is, for example $\{x^2,x^3\}$.

There are non-finitely generated subalgebras of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274994/how-to-prove-that-the-algebra-kx-xy-xy2-xy3-dotsc-is-not-finitely-gen).

> Is $R_h$ finitely generated? Probably not? It is not true that $R_{h,y}=\mathbb{C}[y, x^iy^jh]_{0 \leq i+j \leq d-1}$, since $xy \in \mathbb{C}+\langle h,y \rangle$,
> but $xy \notin \mathbb{C}[y, x^iy^jh]_{0 \leq i+j \leq d-1}$.
>
> **Edit:** Could one please present a finite list of generators, if exists.

Thank you very much!

Comment: $\mathbb{C}[h,y]=A\subset R_{h,y}\subset \mathbb{C}[x,y]=S$. $S$ is a finite type module over $A$ and thus, so is $R_{h,y}$ hence finitely generated.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I am not able to find a finite set of generators for $R_{h,y}$ over $\mathbb{C}$. $R_{h,y}$ includes, for example, $\{x^ny\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.