# Non-Noetherian subring of F[X,Y]

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, proof-verification

> I am trying to prove that, for a given field $F$, the subring
>   $$R:=\{p(X,Y)=\sum c_{ij}X^iY^j \in F[X,Y] : c_{0j}=c_{j0}=0 \text{ whenever } j>0\}$$ of $F[X,Y]$ is not Noetherian.

I think I have done it, but I'm new to this stuff so I would really like someone to check it for me.

Here is my solution:

My idea is to exhibit an ascending chain of ideals which does not terminate (this seems to be the easiest way to proceed out of the 3 possible definitions of Noetherian that I know).

The general form of an element in $R$ is
$$c + XYf(X,Y)$$
where $c \in F$ and $f(X,Y)\in F[X,Y]$.

I claim that $(XY)\subsetneq (XY,X^2Y) \subsetneq (XY,X^2Y,X^3Y)\subsetneq\cdots$ is a non-terminating chain.

The general form of an element of the ideal $(XY,\ldots,X^nY)$ is
$$c_1XY+\cdots+c_nX^nY+Y^2[X^2f_1(X,Y)+\cdots+X^{n+1}f_n(X,Y)]$$
where $c_i \in F$ and $f_i\in F[X,Y]$ and this clearly does not have a $X^{n+1}Y$ term.

Does this proof work?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prove that this subring is not noetherian?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274590/how-to-prove-that-this-subring-is-not-noetherian)

Comment: The ring $R$ in this post is not the same as the ring in the linked post: $X \notin R$.

Comment: The ring isn't exactly the same, but the idea for solution seems like a trivial modification of that one. I guess we could say this is solution verification though.

Comment: Yes, I've done the work myself so all I need is a yes or no please?