# If $S$ is a Noetherian ring and $R\subset S$ is a sub-ring, prove that $R$ is Noetherian or a counterexample

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian

**If $S$ is a Noetherian ring and $R\subset S$ is a sub-ring, prove that
$R$ is Noetherian or a counterexample if this assertion is not always
certain.**

I have thought for a long time about this and I come to the following conclusion that I do not know if it is correct:

I think this is not true in general and I think the following can work: we have that $\mathbb{Z}\subset\mathbb{R}$, is there an ideal that is not finitely generated in $\mathbb{Z}$ and that is finitely generated in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274590/how-to-prove-that-this-subring-is-not-noetherian

Comment: You're correct that the assertion is not true, in general, but your counterexample does not work, since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a noetherian ring.  In fact, $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID, so all of its ideals are principal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every field is Noetherian, and every integral domain embeds as a sub-ring of its field of fractions. So one source of counterexamples is non-Noetherian integral domains.

For example, for any field $k$, the field $k(x_1,x_2,\dots)$ of rational functions in infinitely many variables is Noetherian, but its subring $k[x_1,x_2,\dots]$ is not Noetherian.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Why the field $k(x_1,x_2,…)$ of rational functions in infinitely many variables is Noetherian?

Comment: @user424241 Because its a field! Fields have only two ideas: the $0$ ideal and the unit ideal. Why? As soon as an ideal $I$ contains a nonzero element $a$, it contains $a^{-1}a=1$, and then it contains $b1=b$ for every element $b$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman What is the inverse element of an element in $k(x_1,x_2,...)$ and why is it in $k(x_1,x_2,...)$?

Comment: I assume you mean multiplicative inverse? It is the reciprocal... $k(x_1,x_2,\dots)$ is the field of rational functions in the variables $x_1,x_2,\dots$. That is, it's the [field of fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions) of the polynomial ring $k[x_1,x_2,\dots]$. So an element of $k(x_1,x_2,\dots)$ is a fraction of the form $p/q$, where $p$ and $q$ are polynomials in the variables $x_1,x_2,\dots$, and the inverse of this element is $q/p$ (unless $p = 0$, in which case $p/q = 0$).

Answer (score 1):

Since I run into this very same question for didactical reasons, I believe it could be useful to have other examples at hand.

Personally, I would contribute with the ring $\mathbb{Z}\left[\sqrt{p}\mid p \text{ is a positive prime number}\right]$ obtained by adding to $\mathbb{Z}$ all the real roots of positive prime numbers, which is a subring of $\mathbb{R}$ but it is not Noetherian. Indeed, the ideal
$$\langle \sqrt{p} \mid p \text{ is a positive prime number} \rangle$$
is not finitely generated.