# Infinite type algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

Maybe this question is trivial : most of the algebras I encounter (issued from invariant theory !) are of finite type. Does someone have a 'simple' example of an algebra/subalgebra of infinite type. In fact, I don't see immediately how to show that some algebra is of infinite type.

For instance, if we take the subalgebra
$$\mathbb{R}[x^{k}+k,\quad k\geq 2]$$
it seems to me to be of infinite type...

Same for
$$\mathbb{R}[x^{k_1}y^{k_2},k_1\geq 1,k_2\geq 2]$$

Is it obvious ?

Comment: Both of your examples are explicitly defined with a finite number of generators, I'm not sure how you expected them to be of infinite type.

Answer (score 1):

Any finite type $K$-algebra is isomorphic to $K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/I$, for some $n\geq 0$ and some ideal $I$. In particular, a finite type $K$-algebra is a Noetherian ring.

Hence any non Noetherian ring containing a field $K$ as a subring will give you a counterexample. The simplest one is $K[X_m, m\geq 0]$.

If you want an example of a finite type algebra having a subalgebra not of finite type, you can take $K[X,Y]$ and $K[XY^k,k\geq 0]$ , since the second one is not Noetherian (see  [How to prove that $k[x, xy, xy^2, \dotsc]$ is not noetherian?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274590/how-to-prove-that-kx-xy-xy2-dotsc-is-not-noetherian))